# How to make CSS transition work with JS .appendChild function?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, svg, vuejs3

Via `mouseenter` event I'm applying following JS function to an `svg path element`:

```
const fadeIn = (event, locale) => {
    event.target.style.fill = 'hwb(' + (120 - score[locale] * 1.2) + ' 0% 0% / 1)'
}
```

This works together with a `transition` from CSS:

```
transition: fill .25s;
```

Problem is that the `stroke` overlaps between `svg paths`, and the only way to bring the hovered element's stroke to the front above all others is by adding to the JS function:

```
event.target.parentElement.appendChild(event.target)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work properly with the `transition`. Applying a class instead is not an option because I need `score` and `locale` parameters inside the `hwb()` color style property.

Is there anything I can do, to ensure the element being at the front AND making the transition work?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to interpolate the colour yourself using Javascript.

A simpler approach might be to create a class for each possible score.  It looks like your scores are between 0 and 100. So you'd only need 101 classes defined.  Eg. something like:

```js
let scoreElem = document.getElementById("score")

scoreElem.addEventListener("input", updateFill);

function updateFill() {
  document.getElementById("rect").setAttribute("class", 'score-' + scoreElem.value);
}

// Initialise fill at startup
updateFill();
```

```css
rect {
  transition: fill 1s;
}

/* Sticking to steps of 10 for this demo */
.score-0 { fill: hwb(120 0% 0%); }
.score-10 { fill: hwb(108 0% 0%); }
.score-20 { fill: hwb(96 0% 0%); }
.score-30 { fill: hwb(84 0% 0%); }
.score-40 { fill: hwb(72 0% 0%); }
.score-50 { fill: hwb(60 0% 0%); }
.score-60 { fill: hwb(48 0% 0%); }
.score-70 { fill: hwb(36 0% 0%); }
.score-80 { fill: hwb(24 0% 0%); }
.score-90 { fill: hwb(12 0% 0%); }
.score-100 { fill: hwb(0 0% 0%); }
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect id="rect" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>

<br>
<input type="range" id="score" name="score"
       min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
```